# Coq datatype - pair of pair with bracket

Tags: types, functional-programming, coq, coqide

I am formalizing a system that support pair of tuple and nat as input for function. However, I have some problem with the pair type in Coq.

From what I have learnt about Coq, pair is defined to be left-associative. i.e. `(1, 2, 3)`and `((1, 2), 3)` have the same type of `nat * nat * nat`. Sometimes, it can be treated as a 3-tuple of nat. One the other hand, `(1, (2, 3))` has type `nat * (nat * nat)`, which is a pair of nat and pair (or 2-tuple).

Idealy, I want to have a system that allows **pair of nat and tuple** and **pair of tuple and nat**. i.e. Both `(1, (2, 3))` and `((1, 2), 3)` are differ from `(1, 2, 3)`. Is there any suggested datatype in Coq for such model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(1, 2, 3)` is just a nice notation for `((1, 2), 3)`, and `nat * nat * nat` is just a nice notation for `(nat * nat) * nat`. So this is already what you want.

If you want to see the parentheses, you should tick *View -> Display parentheses* in **CoqIDE**.

Note that if you wanted triple not encoded as pairs, you could define them as:

```
Record triple (A B C : Type): Type :=
{
  t_fst : A;
  t_snd : B;
  t_trd : C
}
```

Comment: `Set Printing Parentheses.` does the same thing (in case you are not using CoqIDE).